# Calculate Code Metrics fails with Exception

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

I am trying to generate code metrics in VS2010 for a solution which contains 7 projects, but it fails with `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`.

There is no output in any of the windows and no exceptions being reported to the event log, so I am not sure where the issue is coming from or how to track it down. The entire solution compiles correctly.

Every other solution I have tried runs the code analysis correctly, but not this one.

Has anyone run into this or know how I can figure out which piece is failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could never figure out exactly what caused this exception, but the culprit appeared to be the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client` assembly.

This was resolved by uninstalling all of VS 2010 and reinstalling.